# VS2010: Syntax Color Highlighting and Intellisense in a JS file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2010

I have an external *.js file that contains Javascript. How do I get teh same  intellisense and color highlighting as I do in an ASPX page?

Here's my options for the js extension (set to 'Script Editor')
[image: Options]

And here's what it looks like in an ASPX page (How I would like it to look.)
[image: aspx page]

BTW, I did a full reset my Settings, setting them to VB and no luck.

Update to original post:

Cuban suggested I add a reference to the file "jquery-1.3.2.min.js." When I searched my PC for that file using the fastest bestest Search app ever written, it found it it .003 nano seconds in the following locations:

[image: jquery-1.3.2.min.js]

Basically, the file magically appeared in a couple of my throw away VS2010 test web apps and in a VS2008 Common folder. I don't know why it was added or how I got it and why it doesn't appear under the 2010 web app that I am currently working on.

I am interested in learning JQuery, and I imagine having intellisense work would be a great help, not to mention I really would like to get the Intellisense and syntax highlighting working in external js file.

How would I modify the following statement from Cuban? Do I need to set a reference something first?  And what's with the triple slash? I haven't seen this convention before.

Please help the clueless.

Thanks.

```
/// <reference path="../../Content/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close the darn js file and re-open it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference tag.  For our .js files, for jQuery we use:

`/// <reference path="../../Content/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />`

And that gives us Intellisense in our JS files for jQuery.  Just reference whichever script you want Intellisense for and it should work.

Comment: See my updated comment. Note that this is VS2010. I suspect that what may be necessary in 2008 may not be so in 2010.

Comment: George,

I'm using this right now in VS2010 :)  And it is what made intellisense work...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to HTML editor. Highlighted most things for me in VS 2008.

Comment: I did before I posted. It didn't really help highlight the Javascript any better or give me better intellisense.